# collection_select field nested forms rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, nested-forms

I have 3 model the first **user.rb:**

```
class User
 has_many :boards, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :boards
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end
```

The second model its **board.rb**

```
class Board
 has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy , :autosave => true
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
 belongs_to :user
end
```

The third model its post.rb

```
class Post
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :board
end
```

I want create a new post with a **parent board** in my action new from **posts_controllers** I have:

```
@post = Post.new
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @post }
end
```

I create a new board with:

```
def create
  @board = current_user.boards.new(params[:board])
   respond_to do |format|
    if @board.save
      format.html { redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @board, status: :created, location: @board }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @board.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

In partial **_form.thml.erb** I have this:

```
<%= form_for(@post, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :content %><br />
<%= f.text_area :content %>
<%= f.collection_select :board_id, Board.all, :id, :name%>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that in my select field **appear every boards**. **I want only show and choose the boards that belongs_to the current_user.**

**Note** I'm using mongoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model can be simpler.

```
class User
 has_many :boards, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :boards
end

class Board
 has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy , :autosave => true
 belongs_to :user
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end

class Post
 belongs_to :board
end

<%= form_for(@post, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :content %><br />
<%= f.text_area :content %>
<%= f.collection_select :board_id, Board.find_by_user_id(current_user.id), :id, :name%>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks find_by_user_id dont working for mongoid :(. Im using mongoid. Thanks!

Comment: Add this to your post class: scope :by_board, lambda |board_id| { where('board_id = ?', board_id) }

Comment: Thanks but I get: **Syntax error!**. I have check with this:  **Board.where(:user_id == 'current_user.id')** but I get every boards again :S. Why get **every boards** if the :user_id key in board its the same that current_user.id?

Comment: the problem has been solved :D The sentence its `Board.where(:user_id => current_user.id)`